# Smallest nonhamiltonian 2-connected bicubic graph with chromatic index 3

Tags: graph-theory

I found this rather trivial example for a bicubic nonhamiltonian 2-connected graph with chromatic index 3:

$\hskip0.5in$ [image: 20 vertex bicubic nonhamiltonian 2-connected graph with chromatic index 3]

Is this the smallest one? If not can you construct a smaller one?

Comment: The smallest example in Mathematica's GraphData database has 50 vertices. (This database is far from exhaustive: for instance, it only includes 198 of the 645490122795799841856164638490742749440 graphs on 20 vertices, evidently not including this one.)

Comment: @Kundor 50 vertices sounds like [Georges Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeorgesGraph.html), which is 3-connected, an unnecessary property for me at the moment. But thanks for your time...

Comment: Was part of an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3339627/19341

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example is the smallest.

I take it "bicubic" means bipartite and 3-regular. In a bipartite graph, the edge-chromatic number (or chromatic index) is equal to the maximum degree, so every bicubic graph has chromatic index 3.

There are data files of various families of graphs available.  Cubic graphs (apparently meaning connected 3-regular simple graphs) up to 22 vertices are available on [Gordon Royle's website](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/remote/cubics/index.html#graphs), in a format which can be imported into Mathematica.

I ran a command like

```
LG = Import[
    "http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/remote/cubics/cub20.g6"];
```

for each data file size (04 up to 20), then ran

```
Select[LG, (ConnectedGraphQ[#] && ! HamiltonianGraphQ[#] && 
    Min[VertexDegree[#]] == 3 && Max[VertexDegree[#]] == 3 && 
    BipartiteGraphQ[#]) &]
```

to find any nonhamiltonian bipartite ones. (The conditions for connectivity and vertex degree should be redundant, since only connected 3-regular graphs are included in the data.) None exist with fewer than 20 vertices. Moreover, only the one example exists with 20 vertices. Mathematica presents it like this (I have checked that it is isomorphic to yours):

[image]