# double tours embedding of nonhamiltonian bicubic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, surfaces, hamiltonian-path, bipartite-graphs

Can [Georges Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeorgesGraph.html)

[image]

(or any other [nonhamiltonian bicubic graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonhamiltonianBicubicGraph.html) ) be embedded on an oriented surface of genus -2, i.e. a double torus?

If it helps, it would have $F=E+\chi-V=75-2-50=23$ faces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [double torus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleTorus.html) is a sphere with two handles and two holes, so its genus (which is the number of holes, see, for instance, p. 133 in “Chromatic Graph Theory” by Gary Chartrand and Ping Zhang, CRC Press, 2009) is $2$. My search at the House of Graphs of bicubic non-hamiltonian graphs of genus at most two provided the following three graphs: [#6923](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=6923), [#27548](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=27548), and 
[#27678](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=27678).

Comment: Funny, I found the first myself as stated in the comments at HoG.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376651/smallest-nonhamiltonian-2-connected-bicubic-graph-with-chromatic-index-3

Comment: Doesn't look like they have a girth 6 graph. Any idea where to look for that?

Comment: @draks... I don't know. I think you can try to ask about this the House of Graphs guys.

Comment: House of Graphs has recently moved. The updated links are https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/6923, https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/27548, and https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/27678. The links above redirect to the right target for now, but they only promise to do so for the "near future".